# Prompting a User a Second time for Enabling GPS

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Currently working through a problem involving the `navigator.geolocation` in javascript. My current code involks `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. Everything works fine, the user gets prompted and they choose their selection of allow or don't allow. I then handle both success and failure properly. My question becomes, if they selected "Don't Allow" is there anyway in JS to reset whatever variable gets cached to remember their selection with JS? or allowing them to be reprompted? I would like to have an option on the page to re-prompt users to enable it in the future if they originally selected no. It might not be possible, but any input would be appreciated. Thanks!